# Adding User Registration to Django App

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I'm following this tutorial and finished it: http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_forms/README.html

I want to continue and add a register button next to the login button which I did, but I couldn't get it to work.  I tried doing `action = "{% url blog.views.register %}"` but I kept getting the error about no arguments found.  I would post all my code but I'm almost sure it's way off base.  I followed this idea:  http://tea.cesaroliveira.net/archives/460 but I couldn't get it to work right.  What is the best way to implement a registration form?  Can someone give me an example or a guide, even just a short one written out to the approach I should take to add registration features.  I had added a second form in login.html template with `method=post` and `action = "{% url blog.views.register %}"` with another template for registration, register.html

in blog/views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST, instance=post)
    return render(request, 'blog/register.html)
```

and in forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ( "username", "email" )\
```

and in blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from blog import views
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    url(r'^accounts/logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.register , {'next_page': '/'}),
)
```

As far as validation I can worry about that later, I just want to get it to work so that they can click register and bring up a registration template with a form to fill out.  I'm not sure if this requires a new model or not as django has user capabilities built in already.

Any help/advice would be much appreciated.  I just want to see what is wrong with my approach and what a better approach would be.

Comment: Are you trying to take the person to a new page with a registration form? Why not just use a link?

Comment: I was trying to use a link, at the time was a django noob.  I've since learned a lot.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, starting from the top and this is most likely the first reason why your code is probably falling apart, this `{% url blog.views.register %}` is wrong. Per the Django docs on [reverse urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns):

> In order to perform URL reversing, you’ll need to use named URL patterns.

So, to create a reverse url for the registration view, your urlpattern should look like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^accounts/register/$', views.register , name="register"),
)
```

I took out the 'next' item because you can redirect from the view. And in the template, you put:

`{% url 'blog:register' %}`, the left hand argument being the app name and the right-hand arg being the name of the url pattern.

Second, I'm not sure how you're handling the login form, but the register view is expecting an instance that doesn't exist. **Instance** is used when you're UPDATING an existing object. For your registration, that's not what's happening, so it doesn't need to be there.

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST) # filled form/i'm skipping validation for this example
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/') # go to some other page if successfully saved
    else:
        form = UserCreateForm # if the user accessed the register url directly, just display the empty form
    return render(request, 'blog/register.html',  {'form': form})
```

But ultimately, I highly recommend [django-allauth](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth) for user registration/profile stuff.

**UPDATE**: Fixed the reverse url for register.

Comment: I recall reading that snippet, "In order to perform URL reversing, you’ll need to use named URL patterns." just slipped my mind